The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "created_at" component Magento 2

Details : {"0":"The \"componentType\" configuration parameter is required for the \"created_at\" component.","1":"#1 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php:425]\n#2 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php:425]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php:334]\n#4 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php:231]\n#5 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->create() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php:140]\n#6 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Generator\/UiComponent.php:103]\n#7 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Generator\\UiComponent->process() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/GeneratorPool.php:93]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:365]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:68]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:129]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Page\/Builder.php:65]\n#12 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Page\\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout\/Builder.php:65]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Builder->build() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:271]\n#14 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->build() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Layout.php:896]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:293]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/Model\/View\/Result\/Page.php:26]\n#17 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\View\\Result\\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Backend\/Model\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#18 Magento\\Backend\\Model\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->setActiveMenu() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction.php:89]\n#19 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#20 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#21 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#22 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#23 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:111]\n#24 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php:151]\n#25 Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#26 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#27 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/ludxb\/magento-meta-package\/src\/module-weltpixel-backend\/Plugin\/Utility.php:80]\n#28 WeltPixel\\Backend\\Plugin\\Utility->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#29 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/ludxb\/magento-meta-package\/src\/module-weltpixel-backend\/Plugin\/Utility.php:80]\n#30 WeltPixel\\Backend\\Plugin\\Utility->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#31 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php:145]\n#32 Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#33 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#34 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Catalog\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Product\/NewAction\/Interceptor.php:32]\n#35 Magento\\Catalog\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Product\\NewAction\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:245]\n#36 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->getActionResponse() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:212]\n#37 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:147]\n#38 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#39 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#40 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#41 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#42 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:116]\n#43 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#44 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#45 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/justbetter\/magento2-sentry\/Plugin\/GlobalExceptionCatcher.php:37]\n#46 JustBetter\\Sentry\\Plugin\\GlobalExceptionCatcher->aroundLaunch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#47 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#48 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:23]\n#49 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:264]\n#50 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub\/index.php:30]\n","url":"\/brands-labels\/pub\/admin\/catalog\/product\/new\/set\/4\/type\/simple\/key\/46af088484fa43979e1c162bbc7b1684c7ce0bcfde07abe179228732dd0bc7fe\/","script_name":"\/brands-labels\/pub\/index.php","report_id":"1f2fcedc65a1143d71c34e7a5400b5ef9e6322d54fd4be780aa498cbeb4d731c"}


You should update your column & check with the code below:
<column name="created_at">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created time</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>


I am facing the issue in default functionality (add new products and also edit products) I am not getting these issues in my custom module
